# Problem with server export when testing React with Jest and Supertest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, supertest

I'm testing a React app with an Express backend, using Jest and Supertest.  In my current test, I need to stub the fetch, which I'm doing with Supertest.  The problem is, I never get an answer from the agent get(), and thus never get any data back.

I think there is a problem with how I'm exporting my server.  I've tried changing around the exports, from module.exports = app, to module.exports = {app}, to const server = app.listen(port, etc), and module.exports = server.  So far none of the solutions I've found are working.

server.js:

```
const app = require('./app.js');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server running on port " + port));
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const ews = require('express-ws')(app);
const WebSocket = require('ws');
...
app.get("/menus", (req, res) => {
    const menus = MenuRepo.getMenus();
    res.json(menus)
})
...
module.exports = app;
```

home-test.js

```
test("Test that dishes displays", async () => {

    menuRepo.populateMenus();
    overrideFetch(app);

    const driver = mount(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <ShowMenus/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    const predicate = () => {
        driver.update();
        const tableSearch = driver.find('#menuTable');
        const tableIsDisplayed = (tableSearch.length >= 1);
        return tableIsDisplayed;
    };

    const displayedTable = await asyncCheckCondition(predicate, 3000, 200);
    expect(displayedTable).toBe(true);
    const menus = menuRepo.getMenus();
    const html = driver.html();

    for(let i=0; i<menus.length; i++){
        expect(html).toContain(menus[i].dishes.day);
    }
});
```

function I'm using to stub fetch:

```
function overrideFetch(app){

    const agent = request.agent(app);

    global.fetch = async (url, init) => {

        let response;

        if(!init || !init.method || init.method.toUpperCase() === "GET"){
            try {
                response = await agent.get(url);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }

        } else if(init.method.toUpperCase() === "POST"){
            response = await agent.post(url)
                .send(init.body)
                .set('Content-Type', init.headers ? init.headers['Content-Type'] : "application/json");
        } else if(init.method.toUpperCase() === "PUT"){
            response = await agent.put(url)
                .send(init.body)
                .set('Content-Type', init.headers ? init.headers['Content-Type'] : "application/json");
        } else if(init.method.toUpperCase() === "DELETE"){
            response = await agent.delete(url);
        } else {
            throw "Unhandled HTTP method: " + init.method;
        }

        const payload = response.body;

        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

            const httpResponse = {
                status: response.statusCode,
                json: () => {return new Promise(
                    (res, rej) => {res(payload);}
                )}
            };

            resolve(httpResponse);
        });
    };
}
```

I'm expecting that the stubbed fetch will return a list of seven json menus.

Comment: Further debugging shows that it does work, kinda.  The  ```response = await agent.get(url)``` does eventually work, but by that point the test has already failed.

Comment: Turns out the predicate in the test was wrong, it was looking for an element that was always there, so it wasn't waiting for the response first.